# Submit Button corrupting

Tags: django

I have a simple profil page and I want to change the profile picture.

forms:

```
class UserProfilePictureUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['profile_photo',]
```

template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='{% url "update_profil_photo" %}'>
{% csrf_token %}
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="{{ profile_form.profile_photo }}">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-camera"></i>
<span>Change Photo</span>
</button>
</form>
```

views:

```
@login_required
def update_profil_photo(request):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = UserProfilePictureUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Update is successful')          
    else:
        profile_form = UserProfilePictureUpdateForm(instance=user_profile)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

When I click the button the design corrupts. I see very big submit button, link of picture and file upload buttons.

[image]

what's wrong with my approach

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you press submit, the same view is called, and you successfully update the UserProfile instance, but then the form that you previously filled gets passed into the template again. Not 100% sure if this would help, but what I would try:

Remove the `else`, and make the last statement (that previously was inside the `else`) to be executed before the return, outside the if statement.

```py
@login_required
def update_profil_photo(request):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = UserProfilePictureUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Update is successful')          
    
    profile_form = UserProfilePictureUpdateForm(instance=user_profile)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Last idea, in case what I wrote above doesn't help: what you could also be aiming at doing in this situation is that once you successfully updated the user profile, you could redirect to another page (the profile page maybe? so the user can see how the image was updated?). You would do that by adding another `return` inside the `if`, after the message, that redirects you somewhere else.

Comment: unfortunetely the first suggestion is not working. If i cannot find a solution I will be implement second one. Thanks